# "Ignoring source layer Python*" and possible reasons of it

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe

I used to train neural networks for a while but did not use Caffe until recently. For my current task, I use the original code of Guided Policy Search (GPS) algorithm from [here](http://rll.berkeley.edu/gps/index.html) with Caffe-trained policy networks. GPS works and learns more or less the intended policy, but the result of an initial few iterations looks very fishy and illogical to me.

The short question is whether the following two frequently occurring lines during training can be a problem?

```
I0123 09:09:12.799830  6960 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer Python1
I0123 09:09:21.119698  6960 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer Python4
```

The longer question is whether the network architecture is correct or  there is something wrong with it. It may be related to the aforementioned problems and the fact that the graph of the network does not correspond to the description of it (see additional info below).

=== Additional info ===

The created training network has the following description:

```
state {
  phase: TRAIN
}
layer {
  name: "Python1"
  type: "Python"
  top: "Python1"
  top: "Python2"
  top: "Python3"
  python_param {
    module: "policy_layers"
    layer: "PolicyDataLayer"
    param_str: "{\"shape\": [{\"dim\": [25, 30]}, {\"dim\": [25, 6]}, {\"dim\": [25, 6, 6]}]}"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "InnerProduct1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "Python1"
  top: "InnerProduct1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 42
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ReLU1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "InnerProduct1"
  top: "InnerProduct1"
}
layer {
  name: "InnerProduct2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "InnerProduct1"
  top: "InnerProduct2"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 42
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ReLU2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "InnerProduct2"
  top: "InnerProduct2"
}
layer {
  name: "InnerProduct3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "InnerProduct2"
  top: "InnerProduct3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 6
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "Python4"
  type: "Python"
  bottom: "InnerProduct3"
  bottom: "Python2"
  bottom: "Python3"
  top: "Python4"
  loss_weight: 1
  python_param {
    module: "policy_layers"
    layer: "WeightedEuclideanLoss"
  }
}
```

I visualize the network by [Netscope](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/quickstart.html).
The image is available [here](https://yadi.sk/i/d0NFHRb3unbqfw).
Note that blobs Python2 and Python3 are not depicted here as if they are not used.

However, the debug output of Caffe which creates the network seem to use all layers.

```
I0123 09:08:17.156579  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Python1
I0123 09:08:17.157122  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer Python1
I0123 09:08:17.157131  6960 net.cpp:380] Python1 -> Python1
I0123 09:08:17.157140  6960 net.cpp:380] Python1 -> Python2
I0123 09:08:17.157145  6960 net.cpp:380] Python1 -> Python3
I0123 09:08:17.157940  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up Python1
I0123 09:08:17.157953  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 30 (750)
I0123 09:08:17.157956  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 6 (150)
I0123 09:08:17.157959  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 6 6 (900)
I0123 09:08:17.157961  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 7200
I0123 09:08:17.157964  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.157971  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.157974  6960 net.cpp:406] InnerProduct1 <- Python1
I0123 09:08:17.157979  6960 net.cpp:380] InnerProduct1 -> InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.158669  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.158679  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 42 (1050)
I0123 09:08:17.158682  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 11400
I0123 09:08:17.158690  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer ReLU1
I0123 09:08:17.158696  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer ReLU1
I0123 09:08:17.158699  6960 net.cpp:406] ReLU1 <- InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.158704  6960 net.cpp:367] ReLU1 -> InnerProduct1 (in-place)
I0123 09:08:17.158708  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up ReLU1
I0123 09:08:17.158712  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 42 (1050)
I0123 09:08:17.158715  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 15600
I0123 09:08:17.158718  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158722  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158725  6960 net.cpp:406] InnerProduct2 <- InnerProduct1
I0123 09:08:17.158730  6960 net.cpp:380] InnerProduct2 -> InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158814  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158820  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 42 (1050)
I0123 09:08:17.158823  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 19800
I0123 09:08:17.158828  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer ReLU2
I0123 09:08:17.158833  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer ReLU2
I0123 09:08:17.158836  6960 net.cpp:406] ReLU2 <- InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158840  6960 net.cpp:367] ReLU2 -> InnerProduct2 (in-place)
I0123 09:08:17.158843  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up ReLU2
I0123 09:08:17.158848  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 42 (1050)
I0123 09:08:17.158849  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 24000
I0123 09:08:17.158851  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer InnerProduct3
I0123 09:08:17.158855  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer InnerProduct3
I0123 09:08:17.158859  6960 net.cpp:406] InnerProduct3 <- InnerProduct2
I0123 09:08:17.158864  6960 net.cpp:380] InnerProduct3 -> InnerProduct3
I0123 09:08:17.158922  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up InnerProduct3
I0123 09:08:17.158927  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 25 6 (150)
I0123 09:08:17.158929  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 24600
I0123 09:08:17.158934  6960 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Python4
I0123 09:08:17.158954  6960 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer Python4
I0123 09:08:17.158958  6960 net.cpp:406] Python4 <- InnerProduct3
I0123 09:08:17.158962  6960 net.cpp:406] Python4 <- Python2
I0123 09:08:17.158964  6960 net.cpp:406] Python4 <- Python3
I0123 09:08:17.158968  6960 net.cpp:380] Python4 -> Python4
I0123 09:08:17.158999  6960 net.cpp:122] Setting up Python4
I0123 09:08:17.159006  6960 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 (1)
I0123 09:08:17.159009  6960 net.cpp:132]     with loss weight 1
I0123 09:08:17.159016  6960 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 24604
I0123 09:08:17.159020  6960 net.cpp:198] Python4 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159024  6960 net.cpp:198] InnerProduct3 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159027  6960 net.cpp:198] ReLU2 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159030  6960 net.cpp:198] InnerProduct2 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159034  6960 net.cpp:198] ReLU1 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159036  6960 net.cpp:198] InnerProduct1 needs backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159040  6960 net.cpp:200] Python1 does not need backward computation.
I0123 09:08:17.159044  6960 net.cpp:242] This network produces output Python4
I0123 09:08:17.159049  6960 net.cpp:255] Network initialization done.
```

Finally, the policy_layers.py module is defined [here](https://github.com/cbfinn/gps/blob/master/python/gps/algorithm/policy_opt/policy_layers.py)